# Duda con consulta en SQL con Campos en la misma tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

El problema es que tengo una tabla donde tengo las columnas:

-NOMBRE

-APELLIDO_P

-APELLIDO-M

Lo que necesito es seleccionar los 3 campos y juntarlos por decir:

Si yo pongo

**SELECT * FROM T.ALUMNOS
WHERE NOMBRE,APELLIDO_P,APELLIDO_M='HECTOR MARTINEZ RAMIREZ'**

QUE EN EL RESULTADO SE MUESTRE LOS 3 CAMPOS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que hago para que esto pase o alguna solucion ayuda!!

**EDIT.1:**

Puse este codigo y funciona pero no aparecen los datos que quiero de la tabla alumnos solo muestra el nombre completo

**SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(NOMBRE,' ',APELLIDO_P,' ',APELLIDO_M) AS nombre_completo
    FROM T.ALUMNOS)a WHERE a.nombre_completo ='DARLY RIOS GARCIA'**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con concat, puedes encontrar un ejemplo [aqui](https://www.solingest.com/la-funcion-concat-en-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si quieres filtrar por nombre completo considera realizar una subconsulta dentro del ´FROM´ con el propósito de concatenar los tres campos y sobre el resultado de esta consulta realiza el filtro.

Queda algo como esto.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT *, 
    CONCAT(nombre,' ',apellido_p,' ',apellido_m) AS nombre_c
    FROM alumnos) a
WHERE a.nombre_c = 'HECTOR MARTINEZ RAMIREZ';
```

Saludos

Comment: Esto me ayudo pero no me salen los campos de la tabla que necesito solo aparece el nombre edito el post para que veas

Comment: Ajuste la consulta, prueba con esta. Saludos.

Comment: No funciona del todo solo muestra el nombre por separado osea el nombre con el nombre,el apellido con su apellido, pero en esta tabla tengo otros campos como generacion y clave y necesito que se muestren esos campos tambien

Comment: Ajuste la consulta, prueba con esta. Saludos.

Comment: Amigo me acabas de salvar ya funciono perfectamente y muestra todos los campos muchas gracias te lo agradesco.

Answer (score 1):

La opción que me parece mas simple es hacer uso de los operadores lógicos, en este caso `AND` para que indiques cuantas y cuales coincidencias se deben de cumplir al momento de establecer el criterio de búsqueda.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM T.ALUMNOS WHERE NOMBRE = "algo" AND
                              APELLIDO_P = "otro algo" AND
                              APELLIDO_M = "mas algo";
```

Es decir como tratas de obtener el registros de un usuario por su nombre completo, entonces indicas que:

- Los 3 valores son necesarios
- Los valores son exactos (por eso el uso del símbolo de `=`)

Comment: Esto que me pasaste esta bien, me ayudo, pero tengo problemas con la busqueda no hay manera de que pueda ser todo junto el nombre????

Comment: platicame ¿qué problemas tienes con la búsqueda? @VictorA

Comment: Tengo un buscador en html donde quiero buscar el nombre completo ya que son muchos alumnos agrege lo que mencionaste en sql y funciona bien solo que al agregarlo a html no funciono

Answer (score 1):

La función `concat_ws(sep, str1, str2, ...)` junta con el separador especificado en el primer parámetro todas las cadenas a partir del segundo parámetro:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t.alumnos
  WHERE concat_ws(' ', nombre, apellido_p, apellido_m) = 'HECTOR MARTINEZ RAMIREZ'
```